# multiprocessing with python 3 : when my child process is done, it kill the other process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'll try to explain to you my issue.

I want to run different processes at the same time.

So, my goal is:

- Download multiple file at the same time
- When the zip is downloaded, i want to apply processing to all the files it contains using multiprocessing

The problem is that as soon as one file is being processed, all other process are killed.

Here's part of my code :

I.E : I create some process with main.py and reidentify.py

```
MAIN.PY
class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, value):
        pass

class NoDaemonContext(type(multiprocessing.get_context())):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

class MyPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = NoDaemonContext()
        super(MyPool, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def parse_args():
    """Parse arguments"""
    # Some code

def execute(args, row):
    """Execute function"""
    try:
      upload_file = #some code

        # Download study
        download_ = download.Download(
            upload_file,
            # Some code
        )

        # Re-identification
        reidentify_ = reidentify.Reidentify(
            upload_file,
        )
        reidentify_.check_if_dicom_is_reidentify()
        download_.download_study()
        reidentify_.reidentify()

    except Exception as error:
        raise

def main():
    """Main function"""
    try:
        args = parse_args()

        csv_file = pd.read_csv(args.fpath_csv)

        msg = 'Some required CSV columns are missing'
        assert set(csv_file.columns) >= required_columns, msg

        # Create a multiprocessing Pool
        with MyPool() as pool:
            func = partial(execute, args)
            pool.map(func, zip(csv_file.iterrows()))

        LOGGER.info("Completed")

    except Exception as error:
        LOGGER.error(error)
        sys.exit(1)
```

```
REIDENTIFY.PY

class Reidentify:
    """Re-identify class"""
    def processing_data(self, archive_, file):
        """Processing data"""
        # Edit Dicom general fields

    def reidentify(self):
        """Re-identify dicom and save to filepath_output"""
        try:
            # Re-identification of the Dicom
            archive_ = archive.Archive(self.download.filepath_download)
            with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
                func = partial(self.processing_data, archive_)
                pool.map(func, archive_.list_archive_files())

            LOGGER.info(f"{self.filepath_output} is re-identified")

        except DicomAlreadyReidentified as error:
            LOGGER.info(error)
            return
        except Exception:
            raise
```